# Routing traffic from F5 BigIP LB to both EC2 instances and Physical servers together

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, devops, f5

Is there a way to make physical F5 BigIP LB to route traffic to both EC2 instances(Autoscaling) and physical machines? I came across this article https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/using-big-ip-gtm-to-integrate-with-amazon-web-services but it seems it is routing traffic to an entire AWS zone, not to a couple of EC2 instances behind a ELB.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can route traffic to any resources from BIG-IP, whether they are locally defined on the same L3 network or remote, you just need to make sure you have routes defined on BIG-IP pointing in the right direction. If you are trying to cloudburst, you can define priority level in the pool so that your physical servers get the traffic unless the minimum threshold is crossed, at which point the remote servers (other datacenter or cloud servers, doesn't matter) will be automatically engaged.

You can also add orchestration to where your cloud servers aren't up and active unless you are getting close to a threshold, at which point the BIG-IP can trigger an action to spin up those servers, then add them to the pool dynamically. There are many options available to you with BIG-IP